# Why does a steel bar buried inside earth exhibits magnetic property? What will be the effect on it if we put it on the surface of the earth?

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

I'm thinking that it is because the magnetic field inside the earth is stronger than it is on the surface. Please correct me if I am wrong and give detailed solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of any particular steel bar that is buried in the Earth? Also, when you say, "magnetic property," did you have [any particular magnetic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Magnetism) in mind?

Comment: just a common steel bar .yeah,attractive property.

Comment: Why do you think that burying it or unburying it would change anything?

Comment: 'Cause in my book it says that it exhibits magnetic property when buried so I just wanted to know why.

Comment: You might want to add more detail to your question then. Identify the book and its author. More detail about what the book claims. I'm guessing that a lot of people here have not read the same book. Its it possibly an explanation of how metal detectors work? People often use metal detectors to search for buried metal objects, but the detector works equally well for metal objects that are not buried.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the premise of the question is that a steel bar buried in earth can be detected by a metallodetector, as opposed to, e.g., wooden or plastic bar.

For this matter, any steel object exhibits *magnetic properties* in the sense that it is attracted to a magnet - whether the object is buried in earth or not does not really matter. In fact, the same principle is used with objects buried in walls or the ceiling, which are even further from the earth.